# How to loop over each page in laravel paginator

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I've used laravel pagination to retrieve data from a table, I'm able to get the items of the first page but how to loop over each page and get the items from each page

Here is my code

```
public function handle()
{
    $productsInstance = Products::query()->paginate(10);
    $totalPages = $productsInstance->lastPage();

    for ($i=1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
        foreach ($productsInstance as $productInstance) {
            $items = $productInstance->items;

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                // operation performed on each item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The products table I'm querying and paginating is having a record of more than 200k, I'm able to perform the foreach operation on the first page but how to get items from each page

Comment: Is this in the context of displaying results or something in the background? If the latter, try `Products::query()->chunk($chunk_size, $callback);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should install **QueryFilter** package & use that package reference in your **Model**

1. Create Product Model and use App\Filters\QueryFilter;
2. Next in Product Model use below function

   /* scope for filters */

   public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters)

   {

   ```
   return $filters->apply($query);
   ```

   }
3. In Controller or Jobs

   $limit = request()->limit ?? 10;

   $products = Product::filter($filter)->paginate($limit);
4. Route should be to get products-> /api/products?limit=10&page=1